# Notation "&" before expression

Tags: notation

I am a bit confused about the "$\&$" just before an expression.

For example:
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \} \} \\
j = arg \min_{1 \le j' \le |\mathcal{F}|} \&|\mathcal{F}[j']|
$$
where j' is the index of the set in $\mathcal{F}$. What is the meaning of $\& |\mathcal{F}[j']|$?

I have found it in [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00207179.2020.1861331?casa_token=x0Nii1ksXzUAAAAA%3A8ggEcOJcMSdh_Wz2VNTPHKYjU0vIo3EciPMTD9AW5PsVlz233V9PeXSXQ1iHTyX4tWzrxsoDZNg). Here's an [extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaX2M.png).

Comment: Please take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) from which I take this quote: "Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title."

Comment: And you should use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing your mathematical expressions.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo. The version of the article I found looks like this:

[image]

No &.

Probably your version has a LaTeX mistake since & is used when displaying equations in multiple lines.

Comment: Thank you. Are you referring to this? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9304107